# Matlab - Plotting Specific Pixels (image treatment)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram

I'm currently struggling with an image treatment\ data plotting issue and was hoping to get some feedback from people with more experience than myself on this matter.

I'll try and breakdown the problem as to make it more understandable:

1. I have an original image (**figureB - which is the blue chanel of the original image**) of size NxM, from this image I select a specific area to study (**NewfigureB**), size 120x170;
2. I then divide this area into what I called **macropixels** which are 10x10 arrays of data points (pixels);
3. I then apply a mask to the selected area to select only the points meeting certain luminescence conditions;

So far so good. My problem comes when I try to plot a histogram of each of these macropixels when applying the luminescence mask. The final objective is to then find the peaks in these histograms.

so far this is what I've come up with. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

```
%Make the number of pixels in the matrix divisible
Macropixel = 10; %determine the size of the macropixel
[rows,columns] = size(figureB); %determine dimentions of the matrix used in the calculations
MacropixRows = floor(rows/Macropixel); %determine how many macropixels are in a row of the original matrix
MacropixColumn = floor(columns/Macropixel); %determine how many macropixels are in a column of the original matrix

%define new dim for the matrix
rows = MacropixRows * Macropixel;
columns = MacropixColumn * Macropixel;
NewfigureB = figureB(1:rows,1:columns); %divisible by the size of the macropixels created

%select area 
NewfigureB = NewfigureB(1230:1349,2100:2269);

%create luminescence mask
Lmin=50;
hmax=80;
mask=false(size(NewfigureB));
mask(NewfigureB <Lmin)=true;
mask=mask & (NewfigureB<hmax);

%Apply mask
NewfigureB=NewfigureB(mask);


    for jj = 1:Macropixel:120
        for ii =1:Macropixel:170 
        histogram( NewfigureB(jj:jj+Macropixel-1, ii:ii+Macropixel-1))
        end
    end'''
```

Comment: Please add a link to the original image.

Comment: @Hoki I'm using this one as a case study: https://www.google.com/search?q=image&rlz=1C1ASUM_enDE845DE845&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7mOmZr8HlAhX7w8QBHYLOA-MQ_AUIEigB&biw=1536&bih=850#imgrc=QJ7Sqsi_rIj3AM:

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted has too many issues.

I tried to correct it the best I could.
I modified some parameters to feat the sample image I used.
I couldn't find your sample image, so I used the [following](https://ncrtc.in/test-image-name/)

Here is a corrected code (please read the comments):

```
I = imread('Nikon-D810-Image-Sample-7.jpg');

figureB = I(:,:,3);

%Make the number of pixels in the matrix divisible
Macropixel = 10; %determine the size of the macropixel
[rows,columns] = size(figureB); %determine dimentions of the matrix used in the calculations
MacropixRows = floor(rows/Macropixel); %determine how many macropixels are in a row of the original matrix
MacropixColumn = floor(columns/Macropixel); %determine how many macropixels are in a column of the original matrix

%define new dim for the matrix
rows = MacropixRows * Macropixel;
columns = MacropixColumn * Macropixel;
NewfigureB = figureB(1:rows,1:columns); %divisible by the size of the macropixels created

%select area 
NewfigureB = NewfigureB(1230:1349,2100:2269);

%create luminescence mask
Lmin=90;%50; %Change to 90 for testing
hmax=200;%80; %Change to 200 for testing
mask=false(size(NewfigureB));
mask(NewfigureB > Lmin)=true; %I think it should be > Lmin.   %mask(NewfigureB <Lmin)=true;
mask=mask & (NewfigureB<hmax);

%This is not the right way to apply a mask, because the result is a vector (not a matrix).
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Apply mask
%NewfigureB=NewfigureB(mask);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Assuming there are no zeros in the image, you can set masked elements to zero:  
NewfigureB(~mask) = 0;



for jj = 1:Macropixel:120
    for ii =1:Macropixel:170

        %Copy NewfigureB(jj:jj+Macropixel-1, ii:ii+Macropixel-1) into temporary matrix MB:
        MB = NewfigureB(jj:jj+Macropixel-1, ii:ii+Macropixel-1);

        %Remove the zeros from MB (zeros are masked elements).
        %The result is a vector (not a matrix).
        MB = MB(MB ~= 0);

        %histogram( NewfigureB(jj:jj+Macropixel-1, ii:ii+Macropixel-1))
        figure; %Open new figure for each histogram. (I don't know if it's a good idea).
        histogram(MB); %Plot the histogram of vector MB.
    end
end
```

It's probably not exactly matches intentions.
I hope it gives you a lead...